# Using "link_to" how to get html and rails code in same line

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
 <%= link_to 'Received Messages<span class="badge badge info">
 @receivedmessage.count</span>'.html_safe, '/messages/show' %>
```

below is the output i'm getting so far. I have to get the "message count number" inside the badge instead of "@receivedmessage.count"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to interpolate your variable you should use quotes instead of single quotes. Also, you'll need to use `#{}` around your variable. An example:

```
name = 'John'
puts "Hello, #{name}!"
```

Notice how I've used quotes on the second line when using string interpolation and surrounded the variable `name` with `#{}`?

Now, let's apply it to your example:

```
<%= link_to "Received Messages <span class='badge badge info'>#{@receivedmessage.count}</span>".html_safe, '/messages/show' %>
```

**Update**

String interpolation and `html_safe` might not always be a good idea, but since your only interpolating a `count` it should be fine. A better option would be to use what Micha has suggested (using `link_to ... do`):

```
<%= link_to '/messages/show' do %>
  Received Messages <span class="badge badge info"><%= @receivedmessage.count %></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is string interpolation combined with `html_safe` a good idea?

Comment: @spickermann He's only interpolating a count, so it's save to use here. But it might be better to use what Mischa has suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `link_to ... do`, which IMO is cleaner than newmediafreak's answer:

```
<%= link_to '/messages/show' do %>
  Received Messages<span class="badge badge info"><%= @receivedmessage.count %></span>
<% end %>
```